# Insufficient resources for full resupply

Tags: power-grid

At the end of Bureaucracy, what happens if there are not enough available resources to fully resupply a given type? For example, assume the game dictates resupplying 5 Coal but only 3 are available from “the bank” because one player has 2 stored on a plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just supply with what you can. In your case, supply just 2 coal, instead of 3, because one player has been hoarding coal.

From the [rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=698), page 6:

> If there are not enough resources left in the supply, that resource is
>   not fully re-supplied! This might happen, if the players store too
>   many resources in their power plants. The resource tokens in the game
>   are limited.

Comment: This is in fact an important part of the strategy to deny players the resources they need by hoarding them.